# Работа с XML в MS SQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, xml, sql-server, веб-программирование

Есть XML вида:

```
<root>
    <node>
        <node2>
            <node3></node3>
        </node2>
    </node>
    <node>
    </node>
    <node>
        <node2>
        </node2>
        <node2>
            <node3></node3>
            <node3></node3>
            <node3></node3>
        </node2>
        <node2>
            <node3></node3>
        </node2>
    </node>
    <node>
        <node2>
            <node3></node3>
            <node3></node3>
        </node2>
    </node>
</root>
```

Как я могу получить в MS SQL через запрос значения, которые находятся в node3?

Comment: "Есть XML вида:"  - где?

Comment: Действительно не видно? У меня вот отображается http://prntscr.com/a7vldl

Comment: где этот XML находится?

Comment: В таблице MS SQL в колонке типа XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
select
    x.c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(100)') node3
from
    [table] t
    cross apply t.xmlColumn.nodes('//node3') x(c)
```

Если полностью указать путь до узла node3, то план запроса должен построиться чуть более оптимальный

```
select
    x.c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(100)') node3
from
    [table] t
    cross apply t.xmlColumn.nodes('/root[1]/node/node2/node3') x(c)
```